# C# Sorting through a big list of numbers

Tags: c#, numbers

I have a huge list of levels, and how much experience points are required for the level (progressing through levels in a game)

The list:

```
Level 1 - 0 xp
Level 2 - 83 xp
Level 3 - 174 xp
Level 4 - 276 xp
Level 5 - 388 xp
Level 6 - 512 xp
Level 7 - 650 xp
Level 8 - 801 xp
Level 9 - 969 xp
Level 10 - 1154 xp
Level 11 - 1358 xp
Level 12 - 1584 xp
Level 13 - 1833 xp
Level 14 - 2107 xp
Level 15 - 2411 xp
Level 16 - 2746 xp
Level 17 - 3115 xp
Level 18 - 3523 xp
Level 19 - 3973 xp
Level 20 - 4470 xp
Level 21 - 5018 xp
Level 22 - 5624 xp
Level 23 - 6291 xp
Level 24 - 7028 xp
Level 25 - 7842 xp
Level 26 - 8740 xp
Level 27 - 9730 xp
Level 28 - 10824 xp
Level 29 - 12031 xp
Level 30 - 13363 xp
Level 31 - 14833 xp
Level 32 - 16456 xp
Level 33 - 18247 xp
Level 34 - 20224 xp
Level 35 - 22406 xp
Level 36 - 24815 xp
Level 37 - 27473 xp
Level 38 - 30408 xp
Level 39 - 33648 xp
Level 40 - 37224 xp
Level 41 - 41171 xp
Level 42 - 45529 xp
Level 43 - 50339 xp
Level 44 - 55649 xp
Level 45 - 61512 xp
Level 46 - 67983 xp
Level 47 - 75127 xp
Level 48 - 83014 xp
Level 49 - 91721 xp
Level 50 - 101333 xp
Level 51 - 111945 xp
Level 52 - 123660 xp
Level 53 - 136594 xp
Level 54 - 150872 xp
Level 55 - 166636 xp
Level 56 - 184040 xp
Level 57 - 203254 xp
Level 58 - 224466 xp
Level 59 - 247886 xp
Level 60 - 273742 xp
Level 61 - 302288 xp
Level 62 - 333804 xp
Level 63 - 368599 xp
Level 64 - 407015 xp
Level 65 - 449428 xp
Level 66 - 496254 xp
Level 67 - 547953 xp
Level 68 - 605032 xp
Level 69 - 668051 xp
Level 70 - 737627 xp
Level 71 - 814445 xp
Level 72 - 899257 xp
Level 73 - 992895 xp
Level 74 - 1096278 xp
Level 75 - 1210421 xp
Level 76 - 1336443 xp
Level 77 - 1475581 xp
Level 78 - 1629200 xp
Level 79 - 1798808 xp
Level 80 - 1986068 xp
Level 81 - 2192818 xp
Level 82 - 2421087 xp
Level 83 - 2673114 xp
Level 84 - 2951373 xp
Level 85 - 3258594 xp
Level 86 - 3597792 xp
Level 87 - 3972294 xp
Level 88 - 4385776 xp
Level 89 - 4842295 xp
Level 90 - 5346332 xp
Level 91 - 5902831 xp
Level 92 - 6517253 xp
Level 93 - 7195629 xp
Level 94 - 7944614 xp
Level 95 - 8771558 xp
Level 96 - 9684577 xp
Level 97 - 10692629 xp
Level 98 - 11805606 xp
Level 99 - 13034431 xp
Level 100 - 14391160 xp
Level 101 - 15889109 xp
Level 102 - 17542976 xp
Level 103 - 19368992 xp
Level 104 - 21385073 xp
Level 105 - 23611006 xp
Level 106 - 26068632 xp
Level 107 - 28782069 xp
Level 108 - 31777943 xp
Level 109 - 35085654 xp
Level 110 - 38737661 xp
Level 111 - 42769801 xp
Level 112 - 47221641 xp
Level 113 - 52136869 xp
Level 114 - 57563718 xp
Level 115 - 63555443 xp
Level 116 - 70170840 xp
Level 117 - 77474828 xp
Level 118 - 85539082 xp
Level 119 - 94442737 xp
Level 120 - 104273167 xp
Level 121 - 115126838 xp
Level 122 - 127110260 xp
Level 123 - 140341028 xp
Level 124 - 154948977 xp
Level 125 - 171077457 xp
Level 126 - 188884740 xp
```

And I'd like to be able to return a level from that list based off xp.

So, for example if I had 200 xp, it would return that I am level 3.
And if I had 4,787,746 xp, it would return that I am level 88
(4,787,746 xp is between levels 88 and 89, so that's why I'd be level 88. You reach a new level only when you have at least the minimum amount of xp required for the level)

So I'd like to be able to achieve the above, without a huge mess of conditional statements. There must be a better way than doing that.

Here's the formula to get the amount of experience required for a level (in case that's of any help):

[image: Formula]

(L is the level you're calculating)

Comment: Google binary search, it should help you out.

Comment: Since you have the formula for xp based on level, you might be able to solve for level and get the reverse formula.

Comment: Is 126 the max level?...or is that simply where the list stopped?

Comment: 126 is max level, yes

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I tried to solve the formula for L without any luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
var levels =
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 126)
        .Select(L => (int)Math.Floor(
                Enumerable
                    .Range(1, L - 1)
                    .Select(x => Math.Floor(x + 300 * System.Math.Pow(2.0, x / 7.0)))
                    .Sum() / 4.0))
        .ToArray();

Func<int, int> getLevel = xp => levels.Where(x => x <= xp).Count();
```

Then this:

```
Console.WriteLine(getLevel(200));
Console.WriteLine(getLevel(4787746));
```

Gives this:

```
3
88
```

You could even do this:

```
Func<int, int> getLevel = xp =>
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 126)
        .Select(L => (int)Math.Floor(
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, L - 1)
                .Select(x => Math.Floor(x + 300 * System.Math.Pow(2.0, x / 7.0)))
                .Sum() / 4.0))
        .Where(x => x <= xp)
        .Count();
```

My timing tests show that this computes a value in under 1 ms so it shouldn't be a performance issue.

Comment: Nice.  Cleaner than mine.  I don't use LINQ very often so my approach is a little more old school.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //*****init for test
        List<Game> g = new List<Game>();

        Game g1 = new Game();
        g1.level = 1;
        g1.xp = 0;
        g.Add(g1);
        g1.level = 2;
        g1.xp = 83;
        g.Add(g1);
        g1.level = 3;
        g1.xp = 174;
        g.Add(g1);
        g1.level = 7;
        g1.xp = 276;
        g.Add(g1);
        //**********

        //setting your xp in order to find your level
        int your_level = 180;
        bool exact_sp = g.Exists(x => x.xp == your_level);

        if (!exact_sp)
        {
            g1.level = -1; //because you do not know
            g1.xp = your_level;
            g.Add(g1);



            List<Game> new_list = g.OrderBy(x => x.xp).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < new_list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (new_list[i].xp == your_level)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your level is: " + new_list[i - 1].level);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < g.Count; i++)
            {
                if (g[i].xp == your_level)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your level is: " + g[i].level);
                }
            }
        }


    }
struct Game
    {
        public int level { get; set; }
        public int xp { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If the xp is the exact number required for the level, this wont work. (It gives the previous level in that case)

Comment: Fixed it tho, thanks for this! I'm also open to see other ways my original request could be achieved :)

Comment: thanks, Brain. I edited the answer. let me know if there is any bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Level(0).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Level(83).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Level(4787746).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Level(188884739).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Level(188884740).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Level(999999999).ToString());
}

private List<int> MinimumExperience = null;

private int Level(int experience)
{
    if (MinimumExperience == null)
    {
        MinimumExperience = new List<int>();
        List<int> numerators = Enumerable.Range(1, 125).Select(x => (int)Math.Floor((double)x + 300D * Math.Pow(2, (double)x / 7D))).ToList();
        for (int L = 1; L <= 126; L++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int x = 1; x < L; x++)
            {
                sum = sum + numerators[x - 1];
            }
            MinimumExperience.Add((int)Math.Floor((double)sum / 4D));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MinimumExperience.Count; i++)
    {
        if (experience < MinimumExperience[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return MinimumExperience.Count;
}
```